# How to prevent infinite loop of custom iterator

Tags: c++

I implemented my first custom iterator, which is supposed to return an `std::pair` at each iteration. The only problem, is it loops infinitely and I do not know how to provide stop condition. The code looks like so:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector> 
#include <utility>


class Simple
{
private:
   std::vector<std::size_t> indices;
   std::vector<int> values;

public:

   void insert(std::size_t index, int value)
   {
       indices.push_back(index);
       values.push_back(value);
   }

   int at(std::size_t index)
   {
       return values[indices[index]];   
   }

   class Iterator
   {
   private:
       const std::vector<std::size_t>* indices;
       const std::vector<int>* values;
       std::size_t pos = 0;
   public:
       Iterator(const std::vector<std::size_t>* indices_, const std::vector<int>* values_, const std::size_t &pos_ = 0): 
           values(values_), indices(indices_), pos(pos_){ }

       bool operator==(const Iterator& other){
           return this == &other;       
       }

       bool operator!=(const Iterator& other){
           return !operator==(other);       
       }

       Iterator operator++() {
           pos++;
           Iterator i = *this;
           return i;       
       }

       std::pair<std::size_t, int> operator*()
       {
           if (pos < (*values).size())
           {
               return std::make_pair((*indices)[pos], (*values)[pos]);          
           }
           std::cout << "EMPTY PAIR" << std::endl; //loops infinitely and prints this message
           return std::pair<std::size_t,int>{};           
       }

       std::pair<std::size_t, int>* operator->()
       {
           if (pos < (*values).size()) 
           {
               std::pair<std::size_t,int> *p;
               *p = std::make_pair((*indices)[pos], (*values)[pos]); 
               return p;       
           }  
           return nullptr;      
       }
   };

   Iterator begin() const
   {
       return Iterator(&indices, &values, 0);   
   }

   Iterator end() const
   {
       return Iterator(&indices, &values, values.size());   
   }
};

int main() {

    Simple s;
    s.insert(10, 100);
    std::cout << s.at(10) << std::endl;
    int i = 0;
    for (const std::pair<std::size_t, int> &p : s)
    {
        std::cout << p.first << " " << p.second << std::endl;   
        if (i > 3) break; // otherwise it will loop infinitely
        i++; 
    }    

    return 0;

}
```

I would like to stress, that this example is simplified and for demonstration purposes, so you may not ask me, why I'm not using map or unorded_map (just because what I'm implementing looks like a map). The question is solely about iterator and I need understanding what may be wrong with iterator itself and how to provide stop condition.

Comment: Take a look at `operator==`. Generally, you'd want the comparison to depend on the values that two iterators hold, rather than the objects themselves.

Comment: @DeiDei. Thanks! I will check it. Though, I'm not sure what condition I should test in my case.

Comment: Perhaps check `pos == other.pos`. At first glance that is what determines the position of the iterator. Once `pos` becomes `values.size()`, it will become equal to the iterator returned by `.end()` and the condition will be met.

Comment: I switched to `return this == &other && pos == other.pos;`, but it still loops for ever.

Comment: That's because `this == &other` is impossible. I didn't say you should keep that. Have only `pos == other.pos`. https://ideone.com/JAyKwS

Comment: @DeiDei. Thanks! Now it works. You may make an answer from this and explain a little bit, what is wrong with `this == &other`.

Comment: `this == &other` can only be true if you compare an interator with itself like in `x == x` but with this definition you can never have two instances that compare equal